# JWT : Multiple public keys to create a token and decode using one private keys

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, jwt

I have a JWT implementation which accessed by multiple clients. In the sense multiple client are sending me JWT token and they are creating the JWT token using the RSA public key I have shared among them. And I am decoding the JWT token using the RSA private key.

But now due to few security reasons I need to send them different public keys and will get the JWT token and I will decode it using one private key I have.

In short how I will generate multiple public keys and single private keys or any similar approach.

Comment: there seem to be a few misconceptions: 1) usually the client doesn't create the JWT. The server (API or Authentication server) does. 2) A token is not signed with a public key. You always need the private key to sign and the public key to verify the token. 3) decoding has nothing to do with the key. The token can be decoded without a key, it's all about verification of the signature. Unless you're talking about encrypted tokens (JWE), but you didn't mention that. It's quite unclear what you really want to achieve and for which purpose you use the JWT.

Comment: here client means : the front end application accessing my application provides me a request data along with few headers and I am getting JWT token as header param.

Comment: but what's the purpose of the token here? Authorization? If it's authorization (the most common use case) then it's not the clients task. And are you only signing the token or do you also send encrypted payload?

Comment: purpose  is Authorization. Because we have multiple front end end applications accessing my application and I am expecting different JWT token , I need to find a common way to decode JWT  and approve the Authorization.

Comment: Then I can only repeat: API or Auth server creates the token, NOT the client. The client doesn't need any key. Server signs with private key. You need to provide an endpoint where the client can sign in to get a token. Tokens will be different for each client, because you'll usually have different user id/client id/audience encoded in the payload. Token signed by clients doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @jps It's maybe true in some OAuth flows but here Amar talks about JWT auth and there is absolutely no reason why a client could not have its own private/public key pair.
Just like client certificate authentication in HTTPS except that here it's only for signature, not encryption of payload.
IMO it's a legitimate flow for client authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (...) send them different public keys and (...) decode it using one private key I have.

As far as I know a RSA private key [can only have **one** public key](https://www.quora.com/Can-one-private-key-have-multiple-public-keys).

> But now due to few security reasons I need to send them different public keys (...)

Are they still "public" if you have to send different public key to each client ?

If I well understand your issue, I would recommend to switch for a PKI with certificates (like X.509) where you are the authority.
The flow would be:

1. The client generate a **private key**
2. The client create a CSR
3. The client send you the CSR
4. You generate a cert with your CA base on the CSR
5. You send back the CRT
6. The client use its private key to sign the JWT
7. The client send you the JWT
8. You check it with your CA

With this solution, you'll get all benefits of client certificate authentication.

If at some point you're not trusting anymore a client you can use a revocation list.

**Btw, I never saw this kind of flow... and since I don't know what's you exactly want to achieve, you should read this as an answer of "How can I implement *client certificate authentication* with JWT ?"**

Answer (score 1):

They should each have their own private signing key. They sign the JWT. They then encrypt the JWT with your public key/cert.

You decrypt the jwt with your private key. You then validate the signature of each party using their public key/cert.

This way the JWT is encrypted and only you can access it. It is signed so you can verify the sender